# .net Windows service account type selection

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, user-accounts

I am new to .net programming and creation of windows service. I want to create a .net windows service that will have to access SQL server 2008 to read/write data and also read excel files kept at network path and write to it. Could you please suggest which account type for the service will be best for this requirement? Can the service access the excel files kept at network paths without any access issues? Also please let me know if any pre-requisites needs to be taken care of.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Give the service a dedicated account and create specific permissions on the share that reveals the excel files. Also means you can log into sqlserver using Windows auth if SQLS knows of the user